# Closing SqlConnection without Closing SQL reader - can it cause connection Leak

Tags: vb.net, connection, memory-leaks, sqldatareader, sqlconnection

I have been using SQLDataReader for fetchig some data from a db. Once I used Reader with the the connection I am closing the connection only and not the Reader. Do we have any possibility of connection leak

Here is the code that I am using

```
 Public Sub Get_SomeData(ByVal sCon As String,ByRef ObjectToReturn As SomeClass)
        Dim sqlCon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(sCon)
        Dim sqlR As SqlDataReader = Nothing
        Dim sqlCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "get_SomeData"
        sqlCon.Open()
        sqlR = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        If sqlR.HasRows And sqlR.Read Then
            ObjectToReturn.Property1 = sqlR("Column1").ToString
            ObjectToReturn.Property1 = sqlR("Column1").ToString
            ObjectToReturn.Property1 = sqlR("Column1").ToString
            ObjectToReturn.Property1 = sqlR("Column1").ToString
        End If
        sqlCon.Close()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, closing the connection will suffice, but a better approach is through the [Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/htd05whh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) statement

```
    Using sqlCon = New SqlConnection(sCon)
        Dim sqlR As SqlDataReader = Nothing
        Using sqlCmd = New SqlCommand
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "get_SomeData"
            sqlCon.Open()
            Using sqlR = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
                If sqlR.HasRows And sqlR.Read Then
                    ObjectToReturn.Property1 = sqlR("Column1").ToString
                    .......
               End If
            End Using
       End Using
  End Using
```

The important part in MSDN docs about Using

> Sometimes your code requires an unmanaged resource, such as a file
>   handle, a COM wrapper, or a SQL connection. A Using block guarantees
>   the disposal of one or more such resources when your code is finished
>   with them. This makes them available for other code to use.
>
> Managed resources are disposed of by the .NET Framework garbage
>   collector (GC) without any extra coding on your part. You do not need
>   a Using block for managed resources. However, you can still use a
>   Using block to force the disposal of a managed resource instead of
>   waiting for the garbage collector.

Comment: Thanks very much .. Sorry for the late response